# Initialization of varray inside a loop in PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to know what happen in memory when initialize a varray collection in every iteration inside a loop like the following example:

```
Declare 
  Cursor cuEmployees Is
    Select id, first_names, last_names
    From   employees
    Order by is;
  Cursor cuNom1(xId_employee employees.id%Type) Is
    Select salary, dependency
    From   nom1.payments
    Where  id_employee = xId_employee;
  Cursor cuNom2(xId_employee employees.id%Type) Is
    Select salary, dependency
    From   nom2.payments
    Where  id_employee = xId_employee;
  Cursor cuNom3(xId_employee employees.id%Type) Is
    Select salary, dependency
    From   nom3.payments
    Where  id_employee = xId_employee;        
  Type nomVarray Is Varray(3) Of cuNom1%Rowtype;
  nomPayments nomVarray;
  va_nuIndex  Integer;
  regPayment  cuNom1%Rowtype;
Begin

  For cu In cuEmployees Loop
    -- Initialize variables per employee.
    va_nuIndex  := 0;
    nomPayments := nomVarray(Null, Null, Null); /* What happen on memory if I do that on every iteration? */
    -- Load info of payments 1.
    va_nuIndex := va_nuIndex + 1;
    Open  cuNom1(cu.numidemp);
    Fetch cuNom1 Into nomPayments(va_nuIndex);
    If (cuNom1%NotFound) Then
      nomPayments(va_nuIndex) := Null;;
    End If;      
    Close cuNom1;
    -- Load info of payments 2.
    va_nuIndex := va_nuIndex + 1;
    Open  cuNom2(cu.numidemp);
    Fetch cuNom2 Into nomPayments(va_nuIndex);
    If (cuNom2%NotFound) Then
      nomPayments(va_nuIndex) := Null;;
    End If;      
    Close cuNom2;
    -- Load info of payments 3.
    va_nuIndex := va_nuIndex + 1;
    Open  cuNom3(cu.numidemp);
    Fetch cuNom3 Into nomPayments(va_nuIndex);
    If (cuNom3%NotFound) Then
      nomPayments(va_nuIndex) := Null;;
    End If;      
    Close cuNom3;
    -- Function that compares info of the payments, select and return what record need to use.
    regPayment := FunctionComparePayments(nomPayments);
    -- ...
  End Loop;
End;
```

What happen on memory? instance a new object on memory for every iteration on the loop or just use the same object on memory.

It's for know as affect performance?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your question is itself wrong!

Initialization has nothing to do with memory. Oracle needs a buffer area to store the fetched rows, not when you initialize. These are basic concepts.